# 400 bad request, while creating a new user via REST API in JasperReports Server

Tags: rest, jasperserver, bad-request

I am trying to create a new user by *JasperReports Server* rest user service api.

But I always get 400 bad request and this is what, I am trying. Can anyone point me what I am doing wrong ?

```
curl -i -u jasperadmin:jasperadmin -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" -X PUT -d '{\"username\":\"mynewuser\",\"password\":\"mynewuser\",\"fullName\":\"NEWUSER\":\"emailAddress:\"user_1@test.com\"}' "http://localhost:8080/jasperserver/rest/user/"

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Pragma: No-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 05:30:00 GMT+05:30
P3P: CP="ALL"
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=F7394A9F7348C22E4B264FBCEB6B828F; Path=/jasperserver
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 971
Date: Mon, 02 Sep 2013 10:32:21 GMT
Connection: close
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was happening because, by mistake I was referring to some old jasper web service doc, which was not matching the version of Jasper Server I was using. Silly mistake on my part.

For reference, the correct url should be something like this `http://example.com/jasperserver/rest_v2/organizations/organization_id/users/<new_user_id>`

I was using commercial edition of jasper server, so i need to include organisation_id in the request url.